# Scalable mobile background

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

I've had a look for the answer high and low, but nothing seems to be working for me.

Basically I am trying to make a scalable background image for mobile/tablet devices on my website.

It seems to be working on mobiletest.me but when I try and open the page on my Samsung Note 1 on both the native browser and Dolphin, the background is really big and not scaled to fit the screen. I haven't had a chance to try it out on any other devices in real life yet, but if you are on a different mobile from me, let me know what you can see. You can see the web page I am building here [testing site](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6185569/Website/mobile/index.html).

Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

Many thanks and best,
Lee-Tze

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, but watch out when u use this. The background image could be pulled out of proportion. But it will fit always the screen size.

```
div
{
   background:url(img_flwr.gif);
   background-size:100% 100%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Thanks. That just makes the width and height stretch to 100%. It still isn't scaling on my mobile phone, it's just stuck at a 'crop'. It scales fine on desktop browsers and mobiletest.me.

Comment: Is there a possibility for a screenshot or something? It's rare that it doesn't fit properly...